# How to iterate over tensors in Keras/TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to rewrite the following piece of Python code in Tensorflow. However, I am having trouble using the `tf.map_fn` for iterating over the tensor.

Here `depth` is the tensor of shape `[batch_size,256,256]`, `normal` is the tensor of shape `[batch_size,256,256,3]` and `scale` is the tensor of shape `[batch_size,256,256]`:

```
for b in range(0,batch_size):
    depth[b,:,:] = [scale[b,0,0] + (scale[b,0,1] - scale[b,0,0])* x for x in depth[b,:,:]]
    normal[b,:,:,:] = [scale[b,0,2] + (scale[b,0,3] - scale[b,0,2])* x for x in normal[b,:,:,:]]
```

I am getting an error message saying:

```
Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing could be simply written as matrix element-wise operations:

```
depth_new = scale[:,0:1,0:1] + (scale[:,0:1,1:2] - scale[:,0:1,0:1]) * depth
normal_new = scale[:,0:1,2:3] + (scale[:,0:1,3:4] - scale[:,0:1,2:3]) * normal
```

Note that we have used ranges for slices of size 1 (e.g. `0:1` instead of `0`, or `3:4` instead of `3`) in order to preserve the axes so that they could be broadcasted (see [TensorFlow broadcasting guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/broadcasting) or Numpy broadcasting guide [here](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html) or [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for more information).